# Extract certain number of words or special characters after a string in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to extract a certain number of words after a particular string.

```
library(stringr)

x <- data.frame(end = c("source: from animal origin as Vitamin A / all-trans-Retinol: Fish in general, liver and dairy products;", "source: Eggs, liver, certain fish species such as sardines, certain mushroom species such as shiitake", "source: Leafy green vegetables such as spinach; egg yolks; liver"))
```

for example to extract the 4 words following "source", I learnt from another question to use this code:

```
trimws(stringr::str_extract(x$end, '(?<=source:\\s)(\\w+,?\\s){4}'))
```

this works very well, however, if I try to select 8 words instead, I noted it does not recognize the "/" and returns NA for the first string.

```
trimws(stringr::str_extract(x$end, '(?<=source:\\s)(\\w+,?\\s){8}'))
```

The question is: is there a regex to include the special characters (or bypass them), so I can still extract the needed words? I noticed that the same happens with other characters (eg - ) or with double white space.

The expected output for 8 words should be something like that:

```
from animal origin as Vitamin A / all-trans-Retinol
```

it does not matter if it counts the / and - as words or not, as I can always adjust the number of quantifiers to be more (in my case, I do not mind extracting more than what I need).

thank you

Comment: Maybe you need `"(?<=source:\\s)\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){3,7}"`? See https://regex101.com/r/xVN62t/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may rely on `\S` shorthand character class that matches any non-whitespace char:

```
(?<=source:\s)\S+(?:\s+\S+){3,7}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xVN62t/2). Details:

- `(?<=source:\s)` - a location immediately preceded with `source:` and a whitespace
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+\S+){3,7}` - three to seven occurrences of 1+ whitespace and then 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/pRaSQ8):

```
library(stringr)
x <- data.frame(end = c("source: from animal origin as Vitamin A / alltrans-Retinol: Fish in general, liver and dairy products;", "source: Eggs, liver, certain fish species such as sardines, certain mushroom species such as shiitake", "source: Leafy green vegetables such as spinach; egg yolks; liver"))
stringr::str_extract(x$end, "(?<=source:\\s)\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){3,7}\\b")
```

Output:

```
[1] "from animal origin as Vitamin A / alltrans-Retinol"
[2] "Eggs, liver, certain fish species such as sardines"
[3] "Leafy green vegetables such as spinach; egg yolks"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can specify the range with `{4,8}`

```
trimws(stringr::str_extract(x$end, '(?<=source:\\s)(\\w+,?\\s){4,8}'))
```

---

Or if it needs to be specific number, do a loop with those number

```
pat <- sprintf('(?<=source:\\s)(\\w+,?\\s){%d}', c(8, 4))
```

then extract the words with the pattern and `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
do.call(coalesce, lapply(pat, function(y) trimws(stringr::str_extract(x$end, y))))
#[1] "from animal origin as"     
#[2] "Eggs, liver, certain fish species such as sardines,"
#[3] "Leafy green vegetables such"
```

Answer (score 1):

> The question is: is there a regex to include the special characters (or bypass them), so I can still extract the needed words? I noticed that the same happens with other characters (eg - ) or with double white space.

Sidenode: This is kind of the XY-Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Your problem is not, that the regex is not working - your problem is that the Regex IS working, but you expect something different. You use it to select the upcoming 8 words, after a certain string - but there are only 6 words before a non-word (`/`) - so that's just no match of your pattern.

So, to provide an "answer" to your question, you should redo your question at first:

WHAT is your exact expectation?

The Solution of akrun would match anything of 4-8 words, but doubt that is what you really need.

Comment: thank you. yes, I should have added the expected outcome to clarify my question (added now). trying to skip the non words (if there is a regex for that). or to extract the special character and keep extracting what is after, for example \\w includes any alphabet, is there another regex to include any alphabet or special character?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `regmatches` + `gsub`

```
lapply(regmatches(u <- gsub(".*?source:\\s+?","",x$end),gregexpr("\\w+",u)),`[`,1:4)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] "from"   "animal" "origin" "as"

[[2]]
[1] "Eggs"    "liver"   "certain" "fish"

[[3]]
[1] "Leafy"      "green"      "vegetables" "such"
```